# WCF Rest does not accept POST

Tags: c#, silverlight, rest

I have downloaded WCFRestServiceWithKey Template from Online Templates in Visual Studio. While the WebGet method works fine, the WebInvoke method does not work at all.

For example:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/AddCustomer", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public Boolean AddCustomer(string firstname)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

A simple call to this method returns method is not allowed. I thought this might be related to clientaccesspolicy.xml but no matter what I do to it I could not figure out.

Here is my clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
 <cross-domain-access>
  <policy>
   <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
    <domain uri="*"/>
   </allow-from>
    <grant-to>
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
   </grant-to>
   </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
  </access-policy>
```

I did not touch the web.config since this came configured with the template file.

Anyone has any idea?

I call the service like this from Silverlight:

```
  http://localhost:6423/PredraWebservice/AddCustomer?apikey=bda11d91-7ade-4da1-855d-24adfe39d174
```

I call it like this:

```
 String send = "<string     xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">String content</string>";

 Uri url = new Uri("http://localhost:6423/PredraWebservice/AddCustomer?apikey=bda11d91-7ade-4da1-855d-24adfe39d174", UriKind.Absolute);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.UploadStringCompleted += new     UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_UploadStringCompleted);
            client.UploadStringAsync(url, send);
```

Comment: try to add `Content-Type:text/xml` in request header

Comment: I have a post on a basic rest webservice with wcf available here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/02/using-rest-wcf-service.html it might give you a good starting point for this

Comment: Could you post the complete call from Silverlight?, maybe you're doing a GET call instead of a POST call....

Comment: Well, I am calling it from a Silverlight application so I guess it sends text/xml instead of SOAP message. How can I fix this from silverlight side?